# Load images from a documents subdirectory into UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

I have several images in png format in "/Documents/saved/" directory.
I loaded this directory into an array called "contents" 
When i use NSLog to view the contents of this array, i see the images as well as a .DS_STORE file
What i want to do is load all these images into UICollectionView cells.

I tried this,

```
[[cell collectionImageView] setImage:
        [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
              [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
```

The collectionImageView is connected to the UIImageView in the UICollectionViewCell

But it doesn't seem to work.EDIT

```
    NSString *dataPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/DImage"];
NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:NULL];
```

NSLog(@"%@", contents);

This gives me the output

```
2013-03-25 10:37:20.186 aUX[543:c07] (
".DS_Store",
"savedImage_0.png",
"savedImage_1.png",
"savedImage_2.png",
"savedImage_3.png",
"savedImage_4.png",
"savedImage_5.png"
)
```

(I have dragged a UIImageView named collectionImageView.)
I need to display these images one by one in the collection view cells.

Comment: A little more code would help.   What is in the `contents` array?

Comment: *What* does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what data types you are using. Maybe breaking up your one-liner might help bring more clarity to the situation. Also, in this way you can check each step with NSLog or in the debugger.

```
NSString *fileName = [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]; 
NSString *path = [filesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImageView *cellImageView =  cell.collectionImageView;
cellImageView.image = image;
```

Maybe your `contents` array contains NSURLs rather than NSStrings. In this way you can find out.

Comment: When i log NSString *path, I get 
Path is .DS_Store
Path is savedImage_0.png
Path is savedImage_1.png
Path is savedImage_2.png
Path is savedImage_3.png
Path is savedImage_4.png
Path is savedImage_5.png
I am just getting a black screen. Maybe it is because of the .DS_STORE file in the beginning ?

Comment: No, you have an array of file names. You need full paths. See change in my answer.

Comment: This works ! Thanks a lot ! But the first cell alone is blank (as it is displaying .DS_STORE file). Any suggestions ?

Comment: C'mon Debbie, you can figure this out! Just check for .DS_Store and remove or not add it to your array.

Answer (score -1):

```
in ur cellForRowAtIndexPath
cell.collectionImage.image=[contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```